# Want to include a sub-folder within GreenBar https with a redirect, but unsuccessful

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site-wide https which is working well with my https redirect. One critical folder, however, does not reflect the GreenBar. This is a login folder and I would prefer to show it as GreenBar to give comfort to the user. Once logged in the GreenBar resumes in the accessed area.  I am looking for a way to GreenBar this connection. The address is nonprofit-cpa.com/amember/login.

The overall site is nonprofit-cpa.com.  My redirect is nonprofit-cpa.com to https://nonprofit-cpa.com/index.html.  The problem link is to the far right under Client Login. This site is not in use, but is fully functional and is close to finishing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  My htaccess follows.  Thanks very much for your time and kind consideration.

Sincerely,

Bob

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteOptions inherit

    # Begin cache control #
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1440 minutes"
    ExpiresByType text/html "now plus 1440 minutes"
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|bmp|png|ico|gff|htm|html|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|gcf)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1440 minutes"
    </FilesMatch>

    # End cache control #

    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://nonprofit-cpa.com [R=301,L]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.nonprofit-cpa.com [R=301,L]
    <Files 403.shtml>
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Files>

    deny from 185.63.253.163
    deny from 185.63.253.183
    deny from 207.67.38.
    deny from 131.72.138.183
    deny from 94.85.246.39

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/nonprofit\-cpa\.com\/index\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You mean the identity bar to the left of the address bar? If so, it's not showing because some parts of the page are being transmitted insecurely, like the `welcomecpa-300x42.png` image in the uploads directory.

Comment: Thanks Mike for taking the time.  I'll have to track down the location to designate it as https.  I'll let you know the outcome.  Bob

Comment: Hi Mike - Once I located the png and set the https it worked beautifully.  Thank you for sharing your knowledge.  Phopher

Comment: Confirmed, it's working properly here too. Going to add my comment as an answer - please accept it in case others have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The identity bar (what you have referred to as the 'Green Bar') will only display if the entire page is secure, and if all assets (scripts, stylesheets, and other resources, such as images) are transmitted over the HTTPS protocol.

In your case, a file by the name of `welcomecpa-300x42.png` in your `uploads` directory was being transmitted insecurely (via HTTP) on a secure (HTTPS) page, as the `href` did not begin with `https://`.

Changing it to `https://` will solve the problem, and the identity bar will appear, confirming that the connection to the page is secure.